# How to target a Nu-get Package to a particular project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a visual studio solution with many projects in it. Among them one of the project is for desktop app too named as **ProjDesktop**. Also one of the Project **ProjWeb** web project in ASP.Net MVC 5.

Behaviour expected: I want to install a Nu-Get package to my Web Project (ProjWeb).

Solution Attempted: I made the **ProjWeb as start up project** and ran below command in Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package foolproof -Version 0.9.4518`

Issue: Package got installed in `ProjDesktop` but I wanted it to get installed to `ProjWeb` as I kept that as StartUp Project.

Question:

1. How can I target a nu-get package to a particular project? Or is it totally Okey for the package to get installed to another project. And I need to add reference or something?
2. Once I install the nu-get package (FoolProof), is there any additional steps required before I start using it. Like manually adding Reference or Something?

P.S: I am a beginner so can someone please guide me here.

Comment: Not sure, why a negative vote. :-|

Comment: Negative vote because (a) it's a duplicate, and (b) if you had googled "nuget install-package" you would have seen the options and been able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @CraigW.: Ok Sir, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-ProjectName` parameter:

```
Install-Package foolproof -Version 0.9.4518 -ProjectName ProjWeb
```

Comment: Sir, your solution worked. But Can you kindly tell me how to verify if that package got added in the project. I mean when I click on references for ProjWeb. I do not see anything like "FoolProof". Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: I have no idea what FoolProof is so can't really help. If it's a normal DLL reference then you should see an entry in there.

Comment: @Unbreakable you dont need to add a reference manually like that, after installing the package, it should be ready to use in your code

Comment: @mxmissile: Sir, you are right. I was looking for exact name as "FoolProof" But it is added as "FoolProofValidation" in reference. Oversight on my end. Sry about that.